# Do plant breeders' rights prevent me from sequencing the genome?

Tags: intellectual-property

The [International Convention for the Protection of New Varieties of Plants (1991)](https://web.archive.org/web/20060821220927/http://www.upov.int/en/publications/conventions/1991/act1991.htm) provides some exclusive rights over particular plants:

> [Article 14(1)(a)] Subject to Article 15 and Article 16, the following acts in respect of the propagating material of the protected variety shall require the authorization of the breeder:
>
> 1. production or reproduction (multiplication),
> 2. conditioning for the purpose of propagation,
> 3. offering for sale,
> 4. selling or other marketing,
> 5. exporting,
> 6. importing,
> 7. stocking for any of the purposes mentioned in (i) to (vi), above.

But, there are exceptions:

> [Article 15(1)] The breeder's right shall not extend to
>
> 1. acts done privately and for non-commercial purposes,
> 2. acts done for experimental purposes and
> 3. acts done for the purpose of breeding other varieties, and, except where the provisions of Article 14(5) apply, acts referred to in Article 14(1) to Article 14(4) in respect of such other varieties.

There's some mention of genotypes, and a brief mention of genetic engineering, but no mention of genome sequencing. I'm not sure how to interpret this convention.

- If I were to use my pocket [full genome sequencer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_genome_sequencing) on an apple of a protected cultivar, would I be violating the law?
- What could I do with that genome sequence? Could I share it? [Ask about it on Stack Exchange?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/97482/28981) Sell it?
- Conventions aren't laws, so: does this vary by jurisdiction?

Answer (score 2):

A U.S. answer - asexually reproduced plants can be protected by plant patents. Most other jurisdictions do not include plants within their patent law.

From the USPTO web site -

> Grant of a plant patent precludes others from asexually reproducing, selling, offering for sale, or using the patented plant or any of its parts in the United States or importing them into the United States. A plant patent is regarded as limited to one plant, or genome.

Sequencing the genome is not listed as something a patent holder can try to prohibit. You might also notice that the US law does not provide a loophole for private use as mentioned in the quoted convention.  You might be able to create a commercial test to see if a particular rise was really genetically identical to a patented one. At least in the US.

Answer (score 1):

> If I were to use my pocket full genome sequencer on an apple of a
> protected cultivar, would I be violating the law?

No.

> What could I do with that genome sequence? Could I share it? Ask about
> it on Stack Exchange? Sell it?

You could do any of the above. The restriction is on the realized genes in plant form in a way that could be used to reproduce the plant, not on the digital representation of the genome.

Even if it is patented, a patent isn't a ban on public disclosure of an invention, it is a ban on the use of the patented idea or process or invention, or the manufacture of it.

And, you can't copyright a genome, at least, not one that you create yourself from a plant. You aren't copying the fixed written form of a document describing a genome, you are authoring it.

> Conventions aren't laws, so: does this vary by jurisdiction?

It could. The Conventions also aren't signed by every country in the world. But, while gene patents do exist, I am not aware of any country that forbids public disclosure of plant genomes (which don't present the privacy issues associated with human genome disclosures).

The National Human Genome Research Institute [summarizes the law of Intellectual Property in Genomics](https://www.genome.gov/about-genomics/policy-issues/Intellectual-Property), which is basically consistent with this account. Gene patents are the primary kind of intellectual property recognized in genetics. And the basic bargain of a patent is that you get a monopoly on commercial use of the invention in exchange for full disclosure of how the invention works as a matter of public record.

Of course, if you used your pocket full genome sequencer to break into a secure locked greenhouse of someone else's property as a burglar to get the genome of the protected cultivar, you would be violating the law and might be engaged in criminal or civil trade secret infringement. But, trade secret status would be lost once the cultivar was marketed commercially, and you could buy one at your local grocery store to get your DNA sample.

Comment: Do you know of supporting references, or is this just one of those obvious consequences of the rules?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I will look for references, although it is a bit hard to prove a negative. IP basically consists of patent, trade secret, trademark, copyright, right of publicity, and maybe a few other minor ones not applicable here. Disclosure isn't barred by patent by its structure. It isn't a right of publicity or trademark case. If you can get access to it, it isn't a trade secret. And the biggest leap I'm making it that it isn't copyrightable (in part, for lack of originality, the genome just copies a real world thing).

Comment: One important point that's missing in the above:  Some protected cultivars are not sold but licensed.  The grower basically signs a contract under which they are provided plant material to grow if they abide by certain terms.  Depending on the terms of the contract, the actions described could be grounds for a civil lawsuit.